# Swap desktops between monitors (windows)

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I want to be able to swap the desktop on monitor 1 with monitor 2.

"What is the best way to swap the part of the desktop which is visible on monitor 1 with the part of the desktop which is visible on monitor 2."

Windows 7 64 / nVidia.

**Swap**

```
Desktop-A -> Monitor-1
Desktop-B -> Monitor-2

-toggle-

Desktop-A -> Monitor-2
Desktop-B -> Monitor-1
```

I thought this was how virtual desktops worked!  The solutions I've found using stretch the desktop across both monitors, or keeps each monitors desktops separate where you can't display Monitor-1/Desktop-A on Monitor-2.

**Clone**

```
Desktop-A -> Monitor-1
Desktop-A -> Monitor-2

-toggle-

Desktop-B -> Monitor-1
Desktop-B -> Monitor-2
```

I've looked at these 
Actual Window Manager,
DisplayFusion,
VirtuaWin,
GiMeSpace,
NirCmd,
Dexpot,
Finestra,
mDesktop, and more... these can move one window at a time, and even specify which monitor a window should open on, but they have no way to swap whole desktops.

I might write an AHK to move the windows for me, but I'm sure there will be snags.  Maybe someone has tackled this for various windows versions, and display dimensions, child windows...

Scenarios:
 1. Move desktop in use to primary monitor.
 2. The second monitor is temporarily unavailable. (tv)

Comment: You have one desktop that spans all monitors, not one desktop per monitor.

Comment: This is true.  What I define as 'Desktop-A/B' is *really* one big desktop.    It would be more correct for me to ask, "How do I swap the part of the desktop which is visible on monitor 1 with the part of the desktop which is visible on monitor 2."

Answer (score 3):

Solutions. Thanks Techie007 for leading me back to looking at scripts:

MonSwap - https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/17885-dual-monitor-swap/ 
Swap all windows from one monitor to the another with Win+Shift+S 
Worked every time in my testing so far.
Can easily modify for 3+ monitors.

Dual Monitor Tools - http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/download.html 
"Rotate" all windows to next monitor. 
Options -> Swap Screen -> Other Windows -> Rotate Screens Forward. 
When 2 of a window class/title, sometimes puts them out of order.

Answer (score 1):

[DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) *can* do this, via [scripting](https://www.displayfusion.com/ScriptedFunctions/Help/).

Here's an example DF custom script that will swap all visible windows between monitors 1 and 2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

public static class DisplayFusionFunction
{
    public static void Run(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        // Get visible window handles on monitors 1 and 2.
        IntPtr[] windowHandles1 = BFS.Window.GetVisibleWindowHandlesByMonitor(1);
        IntPtr[] windowHandles2 = BFS.Window.GetVisibleWindowHandlesByMonitor(2);

        // Iterate through window handles on each monitor, and send each to the other monitor.
        for (int i = 0; i < windowHandles1.Length; i++) {
            BFS.Window.MoveToMonitor(2, windowHandles1[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < windowHandles2.Length; i++) {
            BFS.Window.MoveToMonitor(1, windowHandles2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice!  I may have to install DisplayFusion  :)

Comment: I usually start out searching for AutoHotkey solutions, this time I headed in another direction, and ended up finding AHK again.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the tool call "Desktops" made by Sysinternals. It allows you to have multiple desktops and switching between them with a key-combination. I myself have been looking for similar solution on my windows machine and the closest thing I found was Desktops.

Link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx

Comment: Windows 10 has built-in functionality for this via `ctrl+shift+left/right arrow key`. If you aren't married to the idea of Windows 7, 10 is a great version to use these days for this and a ton of other QoL adjustments.

Comment: @padski - Desktops is nifty, super simple, fast, stable, but it does apply the full desktop = both monitors.  I just want to switch whats on monitor 1 with 2, for the most part, but the core idea is to have a set of 'virtual monitor-sized desktops' which could be each displayed on any monitor, for swapping and cloning.

Comment: @Suresurep I'll agree it has its drawbacks, some transgressions harsher than others. For me, I see the option to live life in the shadows and ensure my toaster is routed through a VPN because the government might know how I like my bagels done... or I can live my life.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

Monitor 1 uses Virtual desktops
Monitor 2 shows pager for Monitor 1

Bonus: The pager would show full screen, and only the 'hidden' desktop(s).