# Shortcut to swap dual monitor ID's?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

So I have dual monitors. I know I can re arrange the layout etc with shortcuts like win+p or fn+f4, or manually through settings.

However, is there a way to swap them totally. For instance, I want monitor 1 to turn into monitor 2 and vice versa with a shortcut.

Running windows 7

Comment: I would write a PowerShell script to swap them completely, and then make *that* a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds simple, but it doesn't have the same simple answer.

First of all, the question needs to be clarified in order to avoid misinterpretations and useless advices.

---

- In this matter, instead of **MONITOR**, it is better to use name **DISPLAY** (Monitor is more often used in the sense of "to_monitor/monitoring", especially for searching).
- I have already asked this question in specialized forums, and it had to be formulated as follows:
  You have 2 displays. Identical. 1-st to your Right. 2-nd Left. How to make the IMAGE of the Left display appear on the right and the IMAGE of the Right display on the left (swap display images)?
  Do not move the displays physically and without touching the cables (which also does not give anything since the picture is attached to the display by Windows)

  *Is it correct for you?*

---

Swap the images between the displays can be done "in parts".
Moving application windows between displays is simple and there are many utilities that do this.
Much more difficult to transfer Windows Desktop elements (icons, shortcuts, wallpaper, toolbars).

This question has already arisen here and some solutions have been proposed:
[Swap desktops between monitors (windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/1080421/swap-desktops-between-monitors-windows)

If you want to solve this issue more competently - you need to go deep into the Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM):  [VidPN Source/Target](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/introduction-to-video-present-networks) and [Connecting and Configuring Displays](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/connecting-and-configuring-displays)  (I'm already doing this).